# Importing `sys` doesn't import all relevant attributes (Python)

Tags: python, importerror, sys

I have two different jupyter notebooks open in the same folder of the same directory. In NB #1, I can import `sys` fine and update `sys.path` accordingly:

```
import sys 
sys.path = ["../../src/"] + sys.path
```

In NB #2, in the *same folder*, the import works fine, but I get this error trying to access path:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-16e3223e69a3> in <module>
      2 from pathlib import Path
      3 
----> 4 sys.path

AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'path'
```

Sure enough, by calling `dir(sys)` in NB #2, I see that there's no `path` attribute:

```
['__breakpointhook__',
 '__displayhook__',
 '__doc__',
 '__excepthook__',
 '__interactivehook__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '__stderr__',
 '__stdin__',
 '__stdout__',
 '__unraisablehook__',
 '_base_executable',
 '_clear_type_cache',
 '_current_frames',
 '_debugmallocstats',
 '_enablelegacywindowsfsencoding',
 '_framework',
 '_getframe',
 '_git',
 '_home',
 '_xoptions',
 'addaudithook',
 'api_version',
 'argv',
 'audit',
 'base_exec_prefix',
 'base_prefix',
 'breakpointhook',
 'builtin_module_names',
 'byteorder',
 'call_tracing',
 'callstats',
 'copyright',
 'displayhook',
 'dllhandle',
 'dont_write_bytecode',
 'exc_info',
 'excepthook',
 'exec_prefix',
 'executable',
 'exit',
 'flags',
 'float_info',
 'float_repr_style',
 'get_asyncgen_hooks',
 'get_coroutine_origin_tracking_depth',
 'getallocatedblocks',
 'getcheckinterval',
 'getdefaultencoding',
 'getfilesystemencodeerrors',
 'getfilesystemencoding',
 'getprofile',
 'getrecursionlimit',
 'getrefcount',
 'getsizeof',
 'getswitchinterval',
 'gettrace',
 'getwindowsversion',
 'hash_info',
 'hexversion',
 'implementation',
 'int_info',
 'intern',
 'is_finalizing',
 'last_traceback',
 'last_type',
 'last_value',
 'maxsize',
 'maxunicode',
 'meta_path',
 'modules',
 'path_hooks',
 'path_importer_cache',
 'platform',
 'prefix',
 'ps1',
 'ps2',
 'ps3',
 'pycache_prefix',
 'set_asyncgen_hooks',
 'set_coroutine_origin_tracking_depth',
 'setcheckinterval',
 'setprofile',
 'setrecursionlimit',
 'setswitchinterval',
 'settrace',
 'stderr',
 'stdin',
 'stdout',
 'thread_info',
 'unraisablehook',
 'version',
 'version_info',
 'warnoptions',
 'winver']
```

In NB #1, surprise, `dir(sys)` yields almost exactly the same output, but `path` is in there.

I'm running both notebooks in the same conda environment; and `sys.version` yields the same thing for both:  `'3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'`.

Does anyone have a clue as to what could be happening? Haven't seen anything like this elsewhere on stack overflow; please direct me if I missed it.

Comment: Not sure if it's related your error, but typically you want to modify `sys.path` in place using `append`, `insert` or `extend` rather than replace it with =

Comment: Where in example NB. 2 is your import from sys and how does it look like?